# Adding one cell in parallel to help a bad cell in a LiFePO4 Batteries bank

Tags: lifepo4

I have a 8 cell 200ah GBS 24v battery bank on my boat.  It is 6 years old and cycled about 1000 time probably.

Just some background first:  I bought the 8 cells from china direct as 2 x 12v packs.  They sent them assembled with bus bars in a cardboard box (WTF).  One if the 12v packs was damaged in transit and 2 of the cells were damaged (like blew the safety plug and incinerated).  This all took forever and in the end they sent me 2 replacement cells.

I now suspect that one of the orphan cells (it is cell 5 in my 8s pack) is getting to its end of life. For a wile now cell 5 has been lagging and sagging in voltage. I don't go below 50% much, but today i was at 52% (about 3.2v per cell) and used my inverter with a 2000w load,  cell five sagged to 2.8v and the BMS went in to low voltage protection.

So finally to the question:
Everybody says you can't mix chemistry and you can't use different capacity batteries in a battery bank; series and or parallel and all of that. And for all good reasons that I understand, so i can't just replace that one cell.

But what I'd like to do is put one cell in parallel with cell 5 just to help it along. Most of the time the bank is sitting in that 3.3 V range, which is the majority of the capacity voltage range for this chemistry of battery. so there in no big delta in voltage.

What is the problem with just paralleling another battery (maybe a smaller one) just with that one cell and then it's capacity relative to the other cells will be a more than it is now, and probably more than all the other cells if looked at individually, and therefore it won't be the "problem" cell anymore.

my BMS uses the lowest or highest cell voltage to determine whether to stop charging or stop discharging so if cell five has a backpack on so to speak with a little extra capacity what's the problem?

It would be an easy cheep way to get the rest of a resalable service life out of my existing battery bank.

Comment: what's  a `resalable service life`?

Comment: 2000 cycles is what the data sheet specifies, and I have no reason to believe the other seven cells will not give me another thousand cycles on top of the thousand I've got already and maybe more so I would say if it wasn't for the damage in Shipping 14 years is what I think is reasonable service life.

Comment: I had no problems doing this with LiFePO4 100 Ah cells. I coupled them for a day via 0.2 ohm resistor to equalize the voltage before the proper connection was made. Check, that there is no increased leakage current in the weak cells.

Comment: @Jens How do i check, that there is no increased leakage current in the weak cells?

Comment: The voltage drop gradient after a charge cycle is an indicator.